# How to use sqlite DATE function with SQLiteDatabase class query method in android?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-cursor

I am using `query` function in the `SQLiteDatabase` class in android for fetching contents from the sqlite database. It works fine. But when I am **trying to use `date`** function of sqlite in my query as follows, **it does not return any rows.**

```
SQLiteDatabase mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
String [] selectionArgs = new  String[] {"date('2016-02-10 00:00:00')"};
String selection = "date(column_name) = ?";
String limit  = 4;

String[] ALL_COLUMNS = new String[] { "id", "column_name","column_name2"};

cursor = mDb.query("table_name", ALL_COLUMNS,selection , selectionArgs, "column_name" + " DESC", limit);

if (cursor != null) {
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        //code to read each row
    }
    cursor.close();
}
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with the above code?

Also, **is there a way to compare the date (and not the time) from the sqlite database using `SQLiteDatabase` class `query` function?**

Answer (score 0):

In SQLite dates are strings. Reference: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html
Therefore, simply remove the `date()` function from the date value and from the column name:

i.e.: change this

```
String [] selectionArgs = new  String[] {"date('2016-02-10 00:00:00')"};
String selection = "date(column_name) = ?";
```

to this

```
String [] selectionArgs = new  String[] {"2016-02-10"};
String selection = "column_name = ?";
```

If you need the time, too:

```
String [] selectionArgs = new  String[] {"2016-02-10 00:00:00"};
String selection = "column_name = ?";
```

See the SQLite supported datetime strings in the link above

Comment: The return value of `date()` contains neither the time part nor quotes.

Comment: @CL Right, as usual. the quotes will be added by Android when susbstituting the parameter(s)

Comment: @HrundiV.Bakshi My object as well as database column saves date and time. So when I compare simply with the value, the query returns values only if both date and time matches. So this approach did not solve my problem. Thanks for the effort.

Comment: @HrundiV.Bakshi I know its late to respond, but I left out a detail from my question. The `column_name` column is storing date and time. So I needed a method to compare 'just date' from the `column_name` with the date object that I have. I was able to solve it by using `String selection = "date(column_name) = date(?)";`